# Symbolicating crash log received by Apple does not work

Tags: ios, error-handling

So, I've now went through literally every question and answer about this on SO without any success. I simply cannot get the crash log I've received through iTunes Connect to symbolicate. As I cannot replicate what Apple did (everything works fine on my end, tried on four simulators and two real devices), I'm on a dead end on what to do.

This is the crash log I've received (shortened):

```
{"app_name":"WeatherBets","timestamp":"2018-04-09 14:43:35.06 -0700","app_version":"1.0.6","slice_uuid":"6db7f787-8665-358e-80e5-6530df342a10","adam_id":1324153355,"build_version":"26","bundleID":"com.maxkrause.WeatherBets","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.3 (15E216)","incident_id":"55525659-1DEC-4243-AC8F-D2FF8227A6AB","name":"WeatherBets"}
Incident Identifier: 55525659-1DEC-4243-AC8F-D2FF8227A6AB
CrashReporter Key:   3ebe972d3b6b31d727d37cd05de1cbfc34ce2b5d
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             WeatherBets [1378]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/935AD89B-3C6E-46E4-9F29-4AB493961AB9/WeatherBets.app/WeatherBets
Identifier:          com.maxkrause.WeatherBets
Version:             26 (1.0.6)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.maxkrause.WeatherBets [690]


Date/Time:           2018-04-09 14:43:34.8351 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-04-09 14:43:15.8797 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3 (15E216)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100efa8c8
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WeatherBets                     0x0000000100efa8c8 0x100ee8000 + 75976
1   Alamofire                       0x00000001010edf0c 0x1010b4000 + 237324
2   Alamofire                       0x00000001010c9188 0x1010b4000 + 86408
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d58b24 0x181d57000 + 6948
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d58ae4 0x181d57000 + 6884
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d656e0 0x181d57000 + 59104
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240f070 0x182321000 + 974960
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240cbc8 0x182321000 + 965576
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018232cda8 0x182321000 + 48552
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018430f020 0x184304000 + 45088
10  UIKit                           0x000000018c30d78c 0x18bff0000 + 3266444
11  WeatherBets                     0x0000000100ef1f80 0x100ee8000 + 40832
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181dbdfc0 0x181dbd000 + 4032

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181eedd84 0x181ecb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208c0a0 0x18208b000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb08 0x18208b000 + 2824

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181eedd84 0x181ecb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208c0a0 0x18208b000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb08 0x18208b000 + 2824

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb04 0x18208b000 + 2820

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbe08 0x181ecb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbc80 0x181ecb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240ee40 0x182321000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240c908 0x182321000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018232cda8 0x182321000 + 48552
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182da1674 0x182d99000 + 34420
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182da151c 0x182d99000 + 34076
7   UIKit                           0x000000018bff27e4 0x18bff0000 + 10212
8   Foundation                      0x0000000182eb1efc 0x182d99000 + 1150716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d220 0x18208b000 + 8736
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d110 0x18208b000 + 8464
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb10 0x18208b000 + 2832

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb04 0x18208b000 + 2820

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbe08 0x181ecb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbc80 0x181ecb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240ee40 0x182321000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240c908 0x182321000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018232cda8 0x182321000 + 48552
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182c3a4b0 0x1829ea000 + 2426032
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182eb1efc 0x182d99000 + 1150716
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d220 0x18208b000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d110 0x18208b000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb10 0x18208b000 + 2832

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb04 0x18208b000 + 2820

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb04 0x18208b000 + 2820

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181eed0f4 0x181ecb000 + 139508
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208fc90 0x18208b000 + 19600
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001815a325c 0x18159c000 + 29276
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189a831a4 0x188fc8000 + 11252132
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189a82db8 0x188fc8000 + 11251128
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189a82b60 0x188fc8000 + 11250528
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189a82f7c 0x188fc8000 + 11251580
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d220 0x18208b000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d110 0x18208b000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb10 0x18208b000 + 2832

Thread 10 name:  WebThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbe08 0x181ecb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbc80 0x181ecb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240ee40 0x182321000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240c908 0x182321000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018232cda8 0x182321000 + 48552
5   WebCore                         0x000000018a5b9dcc 0x18a579000 + 265676
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d220 0x18208b000 + 8736
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d110 0x18208b000 + 8464
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb10 0x18208b000 + 2832

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbe08 0x181ecb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ecbc80 0x181ecb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240ee40 0x182321000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018240c908 0x182321000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018232cda8 0x182321000 + 48552
5   AVFAudio                        0x0000000187e12424 0x187d8c000 + 549924
6   AVFAudio                        0x0000000187e3c834 0x187d8c000 + 722996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d220 0x18208b000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208d110 0x18208b000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018208bb10 0x18208b000 + 2832

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000101c40900   x1: 0x00000001c424b400   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000181f3506c
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001c4252930   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x00000001820878cc  x17: 0x000000010183bf8c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000002
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x00000001018bc6a0  x22: 0x00000001c424b400  x23: 0xa000000004354493
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000101845440  x26: 0x0000000101083000  x27: 0x0000000101845440
   x28: 0x0000000101091000   fp: 0x000000016ef169a0   lr: 0x0000000100efa21c
    sp: 0x000000016ef166d0   pc: 0x0000000100efa8c8 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

I've copied the whole log to my computer and saved it as APPNAME.crash.

These are the three methods I've tried in order to somehow read it:

- Copy the *.crash into the Devices section of Xcode, right-click,
  resymbolicate. Does nothing.
- Use `./symbolicatecrash` in a folder
  with the *.app, *.dSYMs (even copied all dSYMs of my CocoaPods) and
  the *.crash. "No symbolic information found"
- Used the `atos` command
  together with several addresses from the crash log. No success
  either.

So. Where to go from here?

Comment: Did you check if the apps symbols UUIDs matching the UUIDs of your dSYMs? Also, do you have a device with the OS Version ´11.3 (15E216)` and connected it to Xcode so it can at least symbolicate those frames? And please add the binary images section of your crash report and also how you invoked `atos` so we can verify what you did is correct.

Comment: As an additional note: if your app has Bitcode enabled, then you need to download the symbols via Xcode Organizer first. Bitcode results in a new app binary, new framework binaries and new symbols for all these which are all generated on Apples servers.

Comment: Is the directory that's holding your dSYMs indexed under spotlight? Last I knew, that was the method by which Apple's symbolicatecrash(.pl) accessed them. If you're not afraid of debugging perl, you can find the script using `find /Applications/Xcode.app -name symbolicatecrash -type f`.